# how to change profile picture on whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp, profile-picture

I want to access  the dp (profile picture) option of whatsapp using android code I have used that code

**Code**

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

but every time it open with share image option instead of change dp picture option in whatsapp i don't know where i am doing mistake   I hope anyone here can help me. Thanks

guys i corrected question what actually i am asking

Comment: you cant change it through other app

Answer (score 3):

Finally after 1 day of exploring I came up with the **Solution**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.setDataAndType(uri), "image/jpg");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set image as"), 200);
```

With the help of this code snippet, you can set profile photo of **Whatsapp** as well as **Contacts**.

Comment: this code only work less than api 22, in 23 needs file provider can you compatible by adding fileprovider in this code ..i need that

Comment: @NajafAli To implement the file provider.  Please refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751453/4629101) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Whatsapp or share image and video but can't change profile picture from your own app.

Comment: is that possible to set profile picture using the above code how please guide a little

Comment: No, It is not possible.

Comment: then how some apps are using that part like without croping image set your profile picture

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    {
        uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",new File(list.get(position)));
    }else{
        uri=Uri.parse(list.get(position));
    }
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).